# Fetch all data from mongodb

Tags: python, reactjs, mongodb, flask

I'm trying to fetch all the data i have in my mongodb collection and for some reason i can't do it.

I can get more than one result but if i try to get more than x results, it stops working.

I'm using Flask, MongoDB, pymongo to work with mongodb and React.

This is my Flask function.

```
@ app.route("/escoller-centro-proba", methods=["POST"])
@ cross_origin()
def search_proba():
    if request.method == "POST":
        centros = []
        resultadosPing = []
        resultadosNmap = []
        codigo = request.json['codigo'].upper()
        query = {"centro": {"$regex": codigo}}
        resultados = collection.find(query)

        for resultado in resultados:
            centroId = str(resultado["_id"])
            centros.append({"_id": centroId, "sf": resultado["sf"], "centro": resultado["centro"], "concello": resultado["concello"], "lan": resultado["lan"], "dhcp": resultado["dhcp"],
                            "tecnoloxia": resultado["tecnoloxia"], "tecnoloxia_respaldo": resultado["tecnoloxia_respaldo"], "eva": resultado["eva"]})

        if len(centros) > 1:
            return jsonify({"centros": centros, "resultadosPing": resultadosPing, "resultadosNmap": resultadosNmap})

        return jsonify({"centro": centros[0], "resultadosPing": resultadosPing, "resultadosNmap": resultadosNmap})
    else:
        return "Método non POST"
```

And here the JS function.

```
const escollerCentro = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const res = await instance.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/escoller-centro-proba", {
            codigo: codigo.trim().toUpperCase()
        })

        console.log(res.data)

        if (res.data.centro === "O centro non existe") {
            setError("O centro non existe")
            setIsError(true)
            return;
        }

        if (res.data.centros) {
            tabsInfoVar[value].cras = res.data.centros
            tabsInfoVar[value].centro = {
                centro: "",
                resultadosPing: [],
                resultadosNmap: []
            }
        } 
        if (res.data.centro) {
            tabsInfoVar[value].centro = {
                img: img,
                centro: res.data.centro.centro,
                index: res.data.centro._id,
                concello: res.data.centro.concello,
                lan: res.data.centro.lan,
                dhcp: res.data.centro.dhcp ? "Si" : "Non",
                sf: res.data.centro.sf,
                tecnoloxia: res.data.centro.tecnoloxia,
                tecnoloxia_respaldo: res.data.centro.tecnoloxia_respaldo,
                eva: res.data.centro.eva,
                resultadosPing: [],
                resultadosNmap: []
            }
            tabsInfoVar[value].cras = []
        }
        
        tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosPing = res.data.resultadosPing
        tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosNmap = res.data.resultadosNmap

        const resultadosPing = []
        for (var i = 0; i < tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosPing.length; i++) {
            if(tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosPing[i] !== null) {
                resultadosPing.push(tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosPing[i])
            } else {
                console.log("Resultado con valor nulo")
            }
        }
        
        const resultadosNmap = []
        for (var i = 0; i < tabsInfoVar[value]?.resultadosNmap.length; i++) {
            if(tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosNmap[i] !== null) {
                resultadosNmap.push(tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosNmap[i])
            } else {
                console.log("Resultado con valor nulo")
            }
        }

        tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosPing = resultadosPing;
        tabsInfoVar[value].resultadosNmap = resultadosNmap;
        setTabsInfo([...tabsInfoVar])
    }
```

As I said, if i fetch less than 13 results, the code works. I get an array from the database and my frontend can work with it. Here an example: I searched "RIANXO" and it shows me all the results that contains "Rianxo".

[image]

Here I'm searching "CRA", it should show an array of 168 results. Instead, i get this:

[image]

It shows all the results but not an array and as you can see, there is a label ("Show more") that I have to press if I want to see all the data.

I think it is a problem with mongodb, because i did exactly this but working with excel instead of mongodb and had no problem fetching all the data, 1275 results.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. When i saved all the data from excel to mongodb, empty cells filled with NaN value and when the frontend was trying to get the attribute it was displaying the data in the way i have already shown.

The answer was to modify the value of those cells with `df = df.fillna (" ")`.

Here is the code:

```
for index, centro in enumerate(centros):
   data = df[df["Centro"].str.contains(centro)]
   id = df.iloc[index]["ID"]
   centro = df.iloc[index]["Centro"]
   concello = df.iloc[index]["Concello"]
   lan = df.iloc[index]["LAN"]
   dhcp = df.iloc[index]["DHCP"]
   tecnoloxia = df.iloc[index]["Tecnoloxía Acceso Principal"]
   tecnoloxia_respaldo = df.iloc[index]["Tecnoloxía Acceso Respaldo"]
   eva = "Non"
   if dhcp == "Si":
       dhcp = True
   else:
       dhcp = False
   lan = format_lan(lan)
   df = df.fillna("")
   if tecnoloxia_respaldo == "":
       tecnoloxia_respaldo = "Non ten liña de backup"
   centroNovo = {"sf": id, "centro": centro, "concello": concello, "lan": lan, "dhcp": dhcp,
                 "tecnoloxia": tecnoloxia, "tecnoloxia_respaldo": tecnoloxia_respaldo, "eva": eva}
   print(centroNovo)
   collection.insert_one(centroNovo)
```